# Rails query with includes for has_many and belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two model with following associations

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registration
end

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applications, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Now I am trying to do a query like this below

```
@applications = Application.includes(:registration).where("registration.stdniveau = ? AND uni_id = ? AND offer_sent = ? AND (offer_accepted =? OR offer_accepted =?)", 2, @uni.id, 1, nil, 1).references(:registration)
```

I also tried this

```
@applications = Application.includes(:registrations).where("registrations.stdniveau = ? AND uni_id = ? AND offer_sent = ? AND (offer_accepted =? OR offer_accepted =?)", 2, @uni.id, 1, nil, 1).references(:registrations)
```

But both query gives me unreadable error. I don't understand what am I missing here?

Comment: As far as I do know `belongs_to` always take singular value not multiple so it makes it `belongs_to :registration`

Comment: I tried both way with singular and plural

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should make your belongs_to singular: **registration**

2) If you want to make a conditional selection based on another table you need to join it.

3) So this should work:

```
Application.joins(:registration)
.where("registrations.stdniveau = ? AND uni_id = ? AND offer_sent = ? AND (offer_accepted =? OR offer_accepted =?)", 2, @uni.id, 1, nil, 1")
```

Comment: Now I get this error no such column `registration.stdniveau`

Comment: @user1670773, try in where close change a "registration.stdniveau" to "registrations.stdniveau" but keep it singular in model anyway.

Comment: add .reference(:registration) at the end of query